# Why is my phone number not rendering in my specified format in MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

I am trying to get my phone number to render in the following format (xxx)xxx-xxxx. My code is using the @StringFormat, and I am inputting a string. Is there a reason my formatting is not working. Here is my code:

```
<h4>Phone Number: @String.Format("{0:(###) ###-####}", @pts.phone) </h4>
```

Comment: You cannot format a `string` (`String.Format()` is for formatting numeric or `DateTime` values)

Comment: any suggestions

Comment: Use a jquery mask plugin.